# Allow scrolling only when side panel is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jquery mobile's panel feature to create a slide out menu for my mobile app but the number of links in the panel excedes the page length. I also have an event listener in place to prevent scrolling, but it interferes with scrolling to the other links. So what I wanted was to enable the event listen only when the panel was closed and remove it when it was opened. So I came up with this.

```
$('#panel.ui-panel-closed').addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

So when ever the `#panel` has a class of `ui-panel-closed`, the event listen is in placed. But whats ended up happening is that I have to open and close the panel first before it is effected by the javascript. Any ideas on how to get it to work on load. It is wrapped around a on document ready statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

Add it into

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function() {
     $(document).on("touchmove", "#panel.ui-panel-closed", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
     });
});
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, but for some reason its not. I even tried to target just the specific page I needed and even and If statement